# comparing two text files and remove duplicates in python

Tags: python, text, duplicates

I have two text files, `file1` and `file2`.

`File1` contains a bunch of random words, and `file2` contains words that I want to remove from `file1` when they occur.
Is there a way of doing this?

I know I probably should include my own attempt at a script, to at least show effort, but to be honest it's laughable and wouldn't be of any help.

If someone could at least give a tip about where to start, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any specific format?  One word per line?  Randomly structured paragraphs?  Anything will do?

Comment: ugh, I always leave out relevant information. The format of the output doesn't matter, really. The files themselves are just words separated by spaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

get the words from each:

```
f1 = open("/path/to/file1", "r") 
f2 = open("/path/to/file2", "r") 

file1_raw = f1.read()
file2_raw = f2.read()

file1_words = file1_raw.split()
file2_words = file2_raw.split()
```

if you want unique words from file1 that aren't in file2:

```
result = set(file1_words).difference(set(file2_words))
```

if you care about removing the words from the text of file1

```
for w in file2_words:
    file1_raw = file1_raw.replace(w, "")
```

Comment: I don't think you need the list comprehension: `[w for w in file1_raw.split()]` is the same as `file1_raw.split()`

Answer (score 7):

If you read the words into a `set` (one for each file), you can use `set.difference()`.  This works if you don't care about the order of the output.

If you care about the order, read the first file into a list, the second into a set, and remove all the elements in the list that are in the set.

```
a = ["a", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]
b = {"quick", "brown"}
c = [x for x in a if not x in b]
print c
```

gives: `['a', 'fox', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried both your suggestions, here is what I tried with your second one: `a = [open('c:/file1.txt', 'r')]
b = {open('c:/file2.txt', 'r')}
c = [x for x in a if not x in b]  
print(c)` - But I obviously did something wrong, because this is the resulting message: `[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='c:/file1.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>]`

Comment: @Yngve: MattoTodd demonstrated how to read the words, I trust that you worked it out?